# how to get image name from an UIButton on iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uibutton

I'm trying to get the name of the background image from a custom button.

I call this method when I click over the UIButton:

```
-(void)getButtonImageName:(id)sender{       
    UIButton *resultButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@" The button's image is %@.", resultButton.currentImage);
}
```

I can get the title and other properties from the button but not the background image name.

Anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This is the simplest approach to get the current image of a custom button

```
-(void)yesButtonButtonCliked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *tmpYes = (UIButton *)sender;
    [self ClearAllButtons:tmpYes.tag:@"YES"];
    UIImage* selectedImg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxtick.png"];
    if (tmpYes.currentImage == selectedImg ) 
    {

    }
    else
    {
        [tmpYes setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxtick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    NSLog(@"Button tag is %d",tmpYes.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to turn an UIImage into the name used with [UIImage imageNamed:].

do you abuse the image to store data?
What do you try to accomplish with the name of the image?

---

Edit:

> I have several buttons, I want to get the image name when I press a button, switch to another view controller and load that image with the name.

No need to do this, just pass the UIImage instance.
If you want to show a different image based on the name, like you have a thumbnail and want to show the big version in another view controller you have to get the image name from your data model and pass it to the view controller.
How do you decide which button gets which image?

Comment: I have several buttons, I want to get the image name when I press a button, switch to another view controller and load that image with the name.

Answer (score 1):

Following on Matthias's answer "No need to do this, just pass the UIImage instance," which was the solution for me, with the specific code for fellow newbs:

```
Calling .m:
    -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
              //Create an instance of the destination controller
                dmImageZoom *dmz = (dmImageZoom *)[segue destinationViewController];
                //Get the tapped button (the image was in a button) into a button object
                UIButton *btnImg= sender;
                //Get the button's image object
                UIImage *img=btnImg.currentImage;
                //Pass the image object to the destination controller's instance variable 
                dmz.imgPassed=img;

Called .h:
@interface dmImageZoom : UIViewController {
    //Instance variable
    UIImage *imgPassed;
}
    //Property for the object that presents the image
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet  UIImageView *imgView;
    //Property that enables it to be assigned a value
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet  UIImage *imgPassed;

Called .m:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    //Assign the image to view object
    imgView.image=imgPassed;
```

Answer (score 0):

@fluchtpunkt As you say, I have some thumbnails that are UIbuttons with a background image. What happens is that I'm creating as follows for the category selected in the previous view controller. Something like this...

```
if( [strSection isEqualToString:@"animals"] ){
        [button_thumbnail_1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forState:(UIControlState)normal];
        [button_thumbnail_2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState:(UIControlState)normal];
    }
    if( [strSection isEqualToString:@"cars"] ){
        [button_thumbnail_1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forState:(UIControlState)normal];
        [button_thumbnail_2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState:(UIControlState)normal];
    }
}
```

Thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit UIButton:

```
//.h
@interface MySpecialButton : UIButton {
    int mySpecialAttribute;
}

@property (nonatomic) int mySpecialAttribute;

- (void) setBackgroundImage;
- (UIImage*) getImage;

@end
```

And use your special attribute to both set and return the image name:

```
//.m
@implementation LetterButton

@synthesize mySpecialAttribute;
- (void) setBackgroundImage {

    [self setBackgroundImage:[self getImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setBackgroundImage:[self getImage] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}

- (UIImage*) getImage {
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"My_special_image_%i.png", mySpecialAttribute];

    return [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
}

@end
```

Set the class of the button in the xib:

[image: use of MySpecialButton]

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton*)sender;    
 if ([senderButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Hello"]) {
            [senderButton setTitle:@"H" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {
            [senderButton setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

## iOS 11 Swift 4.2

```
@objc func btnWishListAddRemove(_ sender:UIButton){
     let index = sender.tag
     let product_id = array_packageList[index].product_id!

        if sender.currentImage == UIImage(named: "wish list"){
            sender.setImage(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "wishlistfill"), for: .normal)
        }
        else if sender.currentImage == UIImage(named: "wish list fill"){
            sender.setImage(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "wishlist"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
```